# Regex Gets Match Wrong

Tags: .net, regex

This Regex:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9 -.,()/\n/\r]+$
```

in .NET always matches

"#" or "$" or "!" or "%" or "&" or "*" or "+"

So to be clear, this line:

```
Regex.IsMatch("!", @"^[a-zA-Z0-9 -.,()/\n/\r]+$");
```

returns true. Why does that happen?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`-` when used within character class depicts a **range**

So you are trying to match characters from `space` till `.`

Move `-` to end or the beginning of character class or escape it `\-`

Now referring to [ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/) you are specifying a range from ascii decimal value 32 till 46 which includes `!`,`"`,`#`,`$`,`%`........

---

So,it should be

```
^[-a-zA-Z0-9 .,()/\n/\r]+$ 
  ^
```

or

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9 .,()/\n/\r-]+$   
                      ^
```

or escape it

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9 \-.,()/\n/\r]+$   
             ^
```

Comment: ..or put the - directly after a range match, e.g. `[0-9-a-z]`

Comment: Can't he just escape the -? `^[a-zA-Z0-9 \-.,()/\n/\r]+$`

Answer (score 2):

Hyphen in a character class needs to be either at first or at last position otherwise it needs to be escaped. It should work:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9 .,()/\n/\r-]+$
```

Or:

```
^[-a-zA-Z0-9 .,()/\n/\r]+$
```

Or:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9 \-.,()/\n/\r]+$
```